I am having a silly doubt in integrating fractional part of $x$.
I am having a silly doubt in integrating
$\int_{0}^{1}${$x$}$dx$
Let me tell my doubt. That is where I am having my doubt.
We all know that:
$x=\left\lfloor{x}\right\rfloor+${$x$}
Where $\left\lfloor{x}\right\rfloor$ denotes Greatest Integer Function
and {$x$} denotes Fractional Part of $x$.
Now we all know that
$\int_{0}^{1}xdx=\frac{1}{2}$
Which implies that
$\int_{0}^{1}\left\lfloor{x}\right\rfloor dx+\int_{0}^{1}${$x$}$dx=\frac{1}{2}$
Now we all know that
$\int_{0}^{1}\left\lfloor{x}\right\rfloor dx=0$
Which clearly implies that
$\int_{0}^{1}${$x$}$dx=\frac{1}{2}$
But is this concept correct ?
Because we all know that
$0\leq${$x$}$<1$
So,
$\int_{0}^{1}${$x$}$dx$
can have any value between $0$ and $1$.
Why only $\frac{1}{2}$ ?
If, it can also assume other values between $0$ and $1$, then how to find the other values ?
Please help me out with proper explanation.
Is
$\int_{0}^{1}${$x$}$dx=\frac{1}{2}$
correct ?
Best Wishes
Mathematics

Think of the graph of the function. Does that look familiar?

"$\int_{0}^{1}${$x$}$dx$
can have any value between $0$ and $1$" is wrong. The value $\frac12$ of $\int_{0}^{1}${$x$}$dx$ is between $0$ and $1$.

$0\le x\le 1$ on the domain in question. Does that mean $\int_0^1 x dx$ can have any value between 0 and 1? Because that what it looks like your argument for ${x }$, applied to $x$, would say.

Ok. Thank you everyone very very much for helping me out. God Bless you everyone

Actually it took some time for me to understand the answer to this logic of the community members. But I have understood now.

Yeah, there's two parts to the answer to your question: first is seeing where your reasoning went wrong, and second is seeing the right way to reason. I, (and possibly some others who commented) like to do the first part, and let the questioner take care of the second part, if they can. I think you learn a lot more if you don't just get the correct reasoning handed to you, but figure it out for yourself. Good luck going forward!

Whoa!  Whoa!.   If $0 \le x <1$ then $x={x}$.  That's 98% of all you need to know.  And the remaining 2% you need to know is single isolated removable discontinuities (such as the $x=1$ endpoint) of an integral has no effect.

"Because we all know that
0≤
{x}<1"  But not always, everywhere, all at once.  ${\pi} = 0.1415926....$ exactly and can not vary.  And ${0.54} = 0.54$ exactly.  So saying ${x}$ can be any value between $0$ and $1$ so $\int_0^1{x}dx$ can be any value  between $0$ and $1$ is exactly the same as saying: for $3\le x \le 5$ we know $x^2$ can be any value $9\le x^2 \le 25$ so $\int_3^5 x^2\ dx$ can be any value between $18$ and $50$ so why $32\frac 23$?  ... exactly the same reasoning, and exactly the same error...

[Namely the error is.  Although ${x}$ (or any $f(x)$ for that matter) can be any value, it is dependent upon the value of $x$ and for any specific value of the varying variable $x$ will have a specific value]

For $0\leq x\lt1 , x=\{x\} \implies\int^1_0xdx=\int_0^1\{x\}dx$ (1). By your logic $I=\int_0^1\{x\}dx$ . can have any value in $[0,1]$. Assume for contradiction $I=c^*, c\in[0, \frac{1}{2})\cup (\frac{1}{2},1].$
Then $$\int_0^1xdx=\int_0^1\{x\}dx=I=c^*\implies\int_0^1xdx=c^*$$
Which is clearly a contradiction since , as you pointed out , $\int_0^1xdx=\frac{1}{2}$, this implies that $I=\frac{1}{2}$.
The part you probably got confused on is that $0\leq \{x\}\lt1 \implies\int_0^10dx\leq\int_0^1\{x\}dx\leq\int_0^11dx\iff0\leq\int_0^1\{x\}
dx\leq\ 1$ Does not mean that $\int_0^1\{x\}dx$ can take any value between $0$ and $1$.

Yes, the integral of fractional part of x from 0 to 1 is indeed half.
Considering:
x = {x} + [x];
we can always write {x} = x - [x].
Utilizing this approach in the above stated problem, {x} returns back as x - 0; which in turn gives the output as 1/2.
This approach can also be verified by using graphs, where the graph of fractional part of x is a straight line with slope = 1 and the integral only denotes the area under the given curve, in our case - the curve of fractional part of x, as shown below:

